# Angular 4 | duplicate api value when refresh by setInterval()

Tags: angular, subscribe

Good day, im having duplicate value when i set interval to get apidata on my app.

```
// subscribe to API data every 10 seconds
    this.apiTimer = setInterval(() => {
        this.getVoicepickData();
    }, (this.counter*1000));  

//subscribe to API Data
getVoicepickData() {
    this.showLoader();
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data
        this.hideLoader();

    })
}
```

in my application, i set interval every 10 seconds to get new APIDATA but im having duplicate value everytime my apidata refreshed. should i destroy first my subscription to detect changes on my app?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? code looks fine , so need to know what is the pupose of setUnterval();

Comment: yes, i think im just having logic error here. all i want to achieve is it will get my APIDATA every 10 seconds. but when it goes refreshed the old data always stay and the new one will append to the old one. and i want to totally set new APIDATA every 10 seconds.. how can i remove my old apidata value and replace with new one?

Comment: I can't find any logic for appending data in your given code